# It is no any erro message showing when using PHP to Connect Mysql Database ,

Tags: php, mysql

It is nothing to show!!! No any error message 
It seems to just print out the word and not trying to connect mysql

*I am using Netbean to build the project* Is it have any problem??  Thankyou

Here is mycode:

```
<?php
   $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
           or die("No");
   print ("Connected");
   mysql_close($link);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Please check below :

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Note: Try to use mysqli instead of mysql, as it is deprecated now.

Comment: Upvote because you're offering an alternative to a deprecated library.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: @Pika Chus may this help you :)